# Looking to create longitudinal data for each user id but i'm not sure how to fill months with no values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is a sample of what my dataset looks like (timeframe = Jan 2019 to Apr 2019):

```
id  date
1   2019-01-04
1   2019-01-17
1   2019-03-12
2   2019-01-01
2   2019-02-02
2   2019-02-13
2   2019-02-23
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
id month count
1  1     2
1  2     0
1  3     1
1  4     0
2  1     1
2  2     3
2  3     0
2  4     0
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case using `crosstab` with `reindex`

```
pd.crosstab(df.id,df.date.dt.month).reindex(columns=range(1,5),fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()
Out[482]: 
   id  date  0
0   1     1  2
1   1     2  0
2   1     3  1
3   1     4  0
4   2     1  1
5   2     2  3
6   2     3  0
7   2     4  0
```

Comment: this worked really well but what If my date range was from July 2018 - July 2019?

Comment: @madsthaks `pd.crosstab(df.id,[df.date.dt.year,df.date.dt.month])`